# jQuery - adjust the padding of menu elements to fit the page width

Tags: jquery, performance

I want to make my main menu to dynamically adjusting the padding of the li elements, based on the total numbers of them and also make it responding on page width changes.

I wrote this jQuery script, which it works up to a point of changing browser's windows width (smaller), but it stops working when I resizing back to big screen. 
After all, any other recommendations on a more efficient way to achieve or to improve the performance of the script are appreciated.

The script:

```
    var menuItems = $(".main-navigation ul.menu > li > a");
    function sizeThePads() {
        var menuItemsCount = menuItems.length;
        var navWidth = $(".main-navigation").width();
        var totalWidth = 0;
        menuItems.each(function(){
            totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
        });
        var remainingWidth = (navWidth - totalWidth) -30;
        var aPadding = Math.floor((remainingWidth / menuItemsCount) / 2);
        menuItems.each(function(){
            menuItems.css({'padding-right':aPadding,'padding-left':aPadding});
        });
    }
    var headerWidth = $(".header").width();
    if (headerWidth > 724) {
        sizeThePads();
    }

    $(window).resize( function() {
        var newSize = $(".header").width();

        if (newSize != headerWidth) {
            if (newSize < 724) {
                menuItems.css({'padding-right':'','padding-left':''});
            }
            if (newSize > 724) {
                sizeThePads();
            }
        }
    });
```

And my html:

```
<nav class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" style="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" style="">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" style="">Jobs</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" style="">Services</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" style="">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" style="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final script, that works... if anyone can suggest ways for better optimization, that will be appreciated.

```
    var headerWidth = $(".header").width();
    var menuItems = $(".main-navigation ul.menu > li > a");

        function sizeThePads() {
            var headerWidth = $(".header").width();
            var menuItemsCount = menuItems.length;
            var navWidth = $(".main-navigation").width();
            var totalWidth = 0;
            menuItems.each(function(){
                totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
            });
            var remainingWidth = (navWidth - totalWidth) -30;
            var aPadding = Math.floor((remainingWidth / menuItemsCount) / 2);
            menuItems.each(function(){
                menuItems.css({'padding-right':aPadding,'padding-left':aPadding});
            });
        }

        if (headerWidth > 724) {
            sizeThePads();
        }

        $(window).resize( function() {
            var newSize = $(".header").width();

            //if (newSize != headerWidth) {
                if (newSize < 724) {
                    menuItems.css({'padding-right':'','padding-left':''});
                } else {
                    headerWidth = newSize;
                    sizeThePads();
                }
            //}
        });
```